# Why suspend a user for 100 years instead of deleting his/her account?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts, account-suspension

I have just discovered that [users can be suspended for 100 years](https://mathoverflow.net/users/503995/kemono-pantsu). This raises the question: why suspend for such a long duration (which practically means banning), instead of simply banning (i.e. straightforwardly deleting the corresponding account)?

Comment: People can recreate their account after deletion.  But a suspension transfers to the new account. It is a violation of the terms of service to try to avoid a suspension by creating what amounts to a wholly new account.

Comment: I can't comment on specific details of mod decisions like in this case, but it might be relevant to dig a little further on public information if you are curious.

Comment: If you think 100 years is long, have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon

Comment: This is not really on-topic here. You can ask at Meta Stack Exchange (the mother of all metas), but it has already been asked many, many times, so perhaps search for the duplicate versions of your question before posting anything. This is not a question about MathOverflow, it's a question for the SE network's staff (people that almost never visit the MathOverflow Meta page).

Comment: [meta.se]: [How long can a temporary suspension be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211217) Some of the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/211217) seem to be related, too.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Your first comment answers my question, I guess. What is strange, then, is that a different account of the same person [has been terminated, instead of suspended](https://mathoverflow.net/review/first-answers/176258).

Comment: @Alex in this case I suggest as little visibility as possible to someone whose main goal is attention. This user is well-known to mods across the network.

Comment: Since this question is, as phrased, not really about a specific user, might it not be appropriate to remove the link to their profile?

Comment: @LSpice: Indeed, I could do it, but I deemed it useful for the readers to see a concrete example of such long-term suspension, in order to better understand what I had in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

People can recreate their account after deletion. But a suspension transfers to the new account. It is a violation of the terms of service to try to avoid a suspension by creating what amounts to a wholly new account.